# Why is $\int_{0}^{t} e^{nt} \mathrm{\ dt} = \frac{1}{n} \left(e^{nt} - 1\right)$? [solved; notation is also faulty in the first place]

Tags: integration, exponentiation, euler-mascheroni-constant

If $e^{nt}$ can also be written as $\left(e^n\right)^t$ or $\left(e^t\right)^n$, $\int_{0}^{t} e^{nt} \mathrm{\ dt}$ can also be written as $\int_{0}^{t} \left(e^{t}\right)^n \mathrm{\ dt}$ which can also be written as … well, what? I need some more steps of calculation in order to understand why the solution is $\frac{1}{n} \left(e^{nt} - 1\right)$.

Comment: Straightforward consequence of the fundamental theorem of Calculus. $\frac{d}{dt} e^{nt} = n e^{nt}$.

Comment: Of course … Why didn’t I think of it?

Comment: B.t.w. using $t$ for the upper bound of integration *and* as the integration variable makes your expression purely nonsense.

Comment: @Bernard I have found this expression in a slide deck of a lecture. What would be the correct integral?

Comment: To use a variable $t$ and a limit $t$ is bad form. You should use a "dummy variable", e.g.
$$\int_0^t \mathrm e^{n x}~\mathrm d x$$

Comment: @Nemgathos: See for instance  Fly by Night's above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^t e^{nz} \mathrm{\ d}z=\left[\frac{1}{n}e^{nz}\right]_0^t=\frac{e^{nt}-1}{n}$$

Comment: $t'$ is the derivative of $t$? :o)

Comment: @Bernard It's a wrong notation to integrate a $f(t)$ function from $0$ to $t$ same variable of the function. Hence it's better to name another variable like $t'$ or $z$ or whatever.

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence The choice $t'$ is terrible, given that "prime" is often used to denote differentiation, e.g. $(t^2)' = 2t$.

Comment: @FlybyNight Well I didn't say I'm ok with it. I am used to see it used a lot, yet I dislike it too.

Comment: Notation fixed.

Answer (score -1):

If $n \not= 0$, you are a fan of the power law, and like complicated answers to simple questions you could  compute $$\int_0^t e^{nx} \, dx = \int_0^t (e^x)^{n-1} e^x \, dx = \int_1^{e^t} y^{n-1} \, dy = \left[ \frac{y^n}{n} \right]_1^{e^t} = \frac{e^{nt} - 1}{n}$$ using the substitution $y = e^x$, $dy = e^x \, dx$.

Comment: You're encouraging people to say that $(\mathrm e^x)' = x\mathrm e^{x-1}$. I know you don't *say* that, but this answer is misleading. Sorry.